# is it possible to do this without using an "if" (asp.net mvc post action method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

according to [anti-if campaign](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/)     it is a best practice not to use ifs in our code. Can anyone tell me if it possible to get rid of the if in this piece of code ?

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Create(OrganisationInput organisationInput)
 {
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(organisationInput.RebuildInput<Organisation, OrganisationInput>());
    }

   var organisation = organisationInput.BuildEntity<Organisation, OrganisationInput>();
   this.organisationService.Create(organisation);

   return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are asking: Yes, it is possible.

Create an abstract class A with an abstract method that returns ActionResult, created via a factory method that uses a dictionary of Func's that creates A-subclassed instances based on Controller state computed from model (in your case, from the controllerInstance.Model.IsValid property value).

Sample code:

```
public abstract class ModelStateValidator
{
  private Controller controller;

  protected Controller Controller {
    get { return controller; }
  }

  public abstract ActionResult GetResult();

  #region initialization
  static ModelStateValidator() {
    creators[ControllerState.InvalidModel] = () => new InvalidModelState();
    creators[ControllerState.ValidModel] = () => new ValidModelState();
  }
  #endregion
  #region Creation
  private static Dictionary<ControllerState, Func<ModelStateValidator>> creators = new Dictionary<ControllerState, Func<ModelStateValidator>>();

  public static ModelStateValidator Create(Controller controller) {
    return creators[GetControllerState(controller)]();
  }

  private static ControllerState GetControllerState(Controller c) {
    return new ControllerState(c);
  }

  internal class ControllerState
  {
    private readonly Controller controller;
    private readonly bool isModelValid;

    public ControllerState(Controller controller)
      : this(controller.ModelState.IsValid) {
      this.controller = controller;
    }

    private ControllerState(bool isModelValid) {
      this.isModelValid = isModelValid;
    }

    public static ControllerState ValidModel {
      get { return new ControllerState(true); }
    }

    public static ControllerState InvalidModel {
      get { return new ControllerState(false); }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())  //I can show you how to remove this one if you are interested ;)
      {
        return false;
      }

      return this.isModelValid == ((ControllerState)obj).isModelValid;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
      return this.isModelValid.GetHashCode();
    }
  }

  #endregion
}

class InvalidModelState : ModelStateValidator
{
  public override ActionResult GetResult() {
    return Controller.View(organisationInput.RebuildInput<Organisation, OrganisationInput>());
  }
}

class ValidModelState : ModelStateValidator
{
  public override ActionResult GetResult() {
    return this.Controller.RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
```

80 additional lines, 4 new classes to remove a single if.

your usage then, instead of if, calls the method like this:

```
ActionResult res =  ModelStateValidator.Create(this).GetResult();
```

NOTE: Of course it should be tweaked to acommodate the code that is between the ifs in your original question, this is only a sample code :)

---

Adds additional unnecessary complexity? YES.

Contains ifs? NO.

Should you use it? Answer that yourself :)

Comment: :D, I just love how you started: "Since you are asking", by the way, could you tell me how do you pass in the controller is there any magical way how you do that, it seems to me that "private Controller controller;" is never set

Comment: also I cannot access Controller.View and RedirectToAction because these are protected Methods, of course I can inherit Controller and expose those

Comment: actually there is a lot of stuff that doesn't really work here, but it looks awesome :)

Comment: and why do you need to override the GetHashCode and Equals anyway ?

Comment: @Omu: You need to override them because ControllerState is used as a key to the Dictionary that contains the creation-delegates. The Controller instance can be injected by some additional injection mechanism, but that would be a little bit more than the 80 LOC so I have omitted it here ;) Jokes aside...the code I have posted obviously does not compile, I only wanted to express the idea and show how much overhead can removal of a single if bring :) I believe that in a different context this kind of pattern would find its usage - and there no ifs involved :)

Answer (score 13):

Looks like a valid use for "if".

The [anti-if campaign](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/) appears to be against the *abuse* of if statments (i.e. too many nested ifs) etc, not for complete eradication of them.

They are Necessary.

Comment: +1 Also use I recommend using ReSharper which helps you in removing unnecessary nesting of If conditions. Thanks

Comment: It seems to be promoting the replace conditional with polymorphism refactoring- http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operator :-)
It's worse, but it's not an if.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid if in this case, as it can only be one of two states.  The anti-if campaign seems more geared to the endlessly open-ended if/else/switch statments.  Looks like a good campaign!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a While loop... but that seems like a glorified if statement.

```
 private static bool Result(bool isValid)
        {
            while(!isValid)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```